# How do i fetch the azure user id from notebook?

Tags: azure-databricks

I have access to azure databricks , i can create python notebooks and run spark commands inside

I want to read the spark user id  . I expect this is my  azure login id

but if if run the below code it gives me below output ,

If my user id is `surender123@auzure.net` then how do i fetch my user id in notebook

```py
userId = spark.sparkContext.sparkUser
print(userId)
<bound method SparkContext.sparkUser of <SparkContext master=spark://99999999999999 appName=Databricks Shell>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're not calling it as a function, but use as a property - you should use it as `spark.sparkContext.sparkUser()` ([doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkContext.sparkUser.html#pyspark.SparkContext.sparkUser)).  But it won't help on Databricks because it returns the name of the system user that runs Spark process, and on Databricks it returns the `root`:

[image]

Instead you can use the `current_user` SQL function ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/current_user.html)) to get actual user name. You can do it from Python (or other languages) with something like that:

```
username = spark.sql("SELECT current_user()").collect()[0][0]
```